# Add cocos2D file into UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a game with 'cocos2D', and some menus etc in "classic" 'objective-C'.
So, as you could understand, I must create only one project. I have integrated the Cocos2D library without problem, but now when i want to run my cocos2D file into my 'UIViewcontroller', I have some troubles :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

@implementation ViewController

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(-100, -50, 480, 480)
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0];
    glView.opaque = NO;
    [director setView:glView];
    [director runWithScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As you could see, my 'UIViewcontroller' is named ViewController, and my cocos2D file, HelloWorldLayer.

I have seen that in the Introlayer file of a cocos2D project, there is no initialization for HelloWorldLayer. I try to do the same code to run my scene but it don't work and gives me the errors :

```
Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:], /Users/jerry-fr/Desktop/TestCocos2DIntegration/TestCocos2DIntegration/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:382

2014-01-10 23:59:50.647 TestCocos2DIntegration[30030:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'
```

How could I fix this sort of error please ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You addChild: a nil object to HelloWorldLayer. Set a global exception breakpoint (see xcode help) and check the callstack to trace back the issue.

Comment: This is strange because it works in my cocos2D project

Comment: It's only strange until you understand what is really happening. ;)

Comment: Lol that's true, but I don't now where it comes from

Comment: Debug it. Set a global exception breakpoint. Check the stack trace, then you'll now which code and under which circumstances tries to add a nil node.